# Is there a way to have a Bootstrap Modal popup with API data in it?

Tags: api, express, bootstrap-modal, ejs

I want to be able to display some data in a Bootstrap 4 Modal Popup however I am receiving some errors.

I made a new include file and put all of the Modal code in there. Secondly, I went and got the API URL using an axios get request. I can get the API data to show on different pages it is just the Modal I can't get it to show and it is giving me errors on. I then passed the API URL through the view.

```
APP.JS
app.get('/serverstatus', async (req, res) => {
var {data} = await axios.get('https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/status/fortnite_server_status')
res.render('serverstatus', data)
})
```

this is the error I am receiving.

```
ReferenceError: /Users/zack/code/Fortnite/views/index.ejs:1
1| <% include includes/header %>
2| <div class="container">
3|   <h4 class="text-center"><u>NEWS</u></h4>
4|   <p class="leading text-center">Updated every minute  to bring you the latest and greatest news!</p>

/Users/zack/code/Fortnite/views/includes/header.ejs:50
48|         </li>
49|       </ul>
50|       <% include serverstatus %>
51|   </nav>
52| 

/Users/zack/code/Fortnite/views/includes/serverstatus.ejs:12
10|       </div>
11|       <div class="modal-body">
12|         <%= message %>
13|       </div>
14|       <div class="modal-footer">
15|         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

message is not defined
```

I expect the output to show API data in the Bootstrap 4 Modal in the navbar. Like I said I can get this to work on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file you are trying to return "data" to the serverstatus.ejs in a wrong way. The right way is `res.render('serverstatus', {data: data})`  However in your serverstatus.ejs file you use "message" instead of "data". Replace `<%= message %>` with `<%= data %>`.

Comment: Still, doesn't work. Chrome is outputting the same error as it did with `<%= message %>`. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: There was a mistake on your code and i updated my answer.

Comment: The same error is still happening `<%= data %>` is not defined